# Laravel 5 Resource Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created a resource controller in Laravel 5, below are the details. However I am having this error when accessing the routes?  I tried all routes and all of them produce the same erro.  NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

```
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 802
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 670
```

**Route.php:**

```
Route::controller('my','myController');
```

**Controller file:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you mark line 161 for us?

Comment: When you have that kind of problems  with routes, start by doing a php artisan route:list to see all your routes, it may help.

Comment: please have a look at this answer it may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/53943911/5068530

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change this:

```
Route::controller('my','myController');
```

To:

```
Route::resource('my','myController');
```

More info about the Resource controllers can be found in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

Comment: Sometimes at least in 5.2 you have to use php artisan route:cache